# Get the element type of each index of an array with mixed types

Tags: typescript

I have a mixed array like:

```
const array = [false, 1, '', class T {}];
```

Whose type is:

```
type arrayType = typeof array; // (string | number | boolean | typeof T) []
```

And the type of an object in any index is:

```
string | number | boolean | typeof T
```

**How can I get the type of the object from a specific index, as below, instead of the union of the types?**

```
const a = array [0] // should be boolean
const b = array [1] // should be number
const c = array [2] // should be string
const d = array [3] // should be typeof T
```

[TS Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gMzgGwgFMAaARhIHJKTh84IIYAVAbwF8BdAbgCheoKAA5F4SVM2GjMgkSBxjkKbjAD0qmAApoCAJZgA5jAA%20MMAFcAtgCMiCEzGsgQ%20InDAPZReSwCUWTn5edR19I1MLGzsHJxc3D1MvH2ZeUEhYOAxFVCwABk41DQgACxBzfAATR1FY13dU8GhHLMQlLDIC9RgSssrqsytbBAb0mGAW8RQsACZOotLyqttuqD1DEaaqzFacgGY57oW%205aSFZiA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a tuple type. You can either be explicit about the type, or you can make TS  infer a tuple type by using an `as const` assertion:

```
const array = [false,1,''] as const;


type arrayType = typeof array; /// readonly [false, 1, ""]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/FAjGHsDsGcBcAICGAnZiCe8C88DaAzRAG2gFMAaARnIHIaBdJaeCGWAbhGFnQAdSkqDABU+AnD37h8gtOnbwA9MvjJSiACZQimAsTLl41eACIT9YEA)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz it is a marker for the TS compiler to change the way it does inference, namely, it will keep literal type, it will keep tuples, and it will make  the tuple readonly   https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510